# How to solve "Preparing wheel metadata ... error" this error for MacOS for python 3.9

Tags: python, macos, terminal, compiler-errors, python-3.9

I am trying to use pip3 with python 3.9 to install modules... I read replies for windows which suggest installing VisualStudio as we need a good C++ compiler

I use macOS

I am adding the input and error message for better understanding

Input:

```
rohansaswade@Rohans-MBP ~ % pip3 install numpy
```

Output:

```
 Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.19.2.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

I did not mention the complete error output as it seems pretty irrelevant, yet if you need it to help me, please drop a comment.

I use macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and python 3.9

Comment: Yes, I do think that details coming after the `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:` line may be of interest to address your issue :-)

Comment: thanks for the input Martin... i depriciated my python version from3.9 to 3.7 and would wait for modules to catchup with it before upgrading

Comment: It solved all my issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue.
In my case, the steps below helped though it was time-consuming.

#Preparation
`pip install cython` 
`git clone https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git`

#Steps
`cd numpy`
`python setup.py build`
`python setup.py install`

I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, what worked for me is to

#Upgrade pip

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```